# PHP Array to String conversion issue

Tags: php, yii

I want to show all data from $result in my table but there's some error.
The notice is "Array to string conversion"
Here's the controller :

```
public function actionIndex()
  {
      $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('
        Select username as user
        From application_admin aa, application a
        Where a.app_id = aa.app_id');
        $reader = $command->query();
        $dataUser = $reader->readAll();

    $dataProvider = Application::model()->findAll();

    foreach ($dataProvider as $data) {
      $temp = array();
              $name = $data->name;
              $customer = $dataUser;
              $category = $data->appCategory->name;

              $temp['name'] = $name;
              $temp['customer'] = $customer;
              $temp['category'] = $category;
              $result[] = $temp;
    }

    $this->render('index',array('result'=>$result));
  }
```

and this is the View :

```
<?php
    $i=1;
        foreach ($result as $data){
  ?>
        <tr class="center clickableRow">
            <div>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['customer'];?></td>   //error in this line
                <td><?php echo $data['category'];?></td>
            </div>
        </tr >

        <?php
            $i++;
        }

  ?>
```

Please give me some advice, thanks

Comment: `var_dump($data['customer'])` and check the contents

Comment: $customer = $dataUser[$j]; may be $dataUser[$j] is an array..! What is it..?

Comment: sorry it's my fault. i do some try and forget to undo, i use $j because i think $dataUser = $reader->readAll(); will return array

Comment: Change `<?php echo $data['customer'];?>` to `<?php print_r($data['customer']);?>`

Comment: @asprin it's show Array([user]=>'customer name') in every <td>

Comment: i just need to echo the content in that array

Comment: thanks asprin you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i get it

```
<td><?php echo $data['customer']['user'];?></td>
```

thanks all